# gitignore ! pattern not repeating for directories with similar file structure

Tags: gitignore

I have a file structure like

```
foo
-/abc
--/v1
---/hij
----/lmno
-----/pqr
------/bar/.gitkeep
------/baz/.gitkeep
-----/stuv
------/bar/.gitkeep
------/baz/.gitkeep
--/v2 (structure repeated)
.gitignore
```

I want to ignore everything except the .gitkeeps in the file structure below the /v1/, /v2/, etc folders.
My .gitignore looks like below, but it isn't including the folder with /baz/.gitkeep, /bar/.gitkeep.
Copy pasting text in .gitignore for every /vX/ that is created is not ideal.

```
foo/abc/**/hij/lmno/pqr/*
!foo/abc/**/hij/lmno/pqr/**/.gitkeep

foo/abc/**/hij/lmno/stuv/*
!foo/abc/**/hij/lmno/stuv/**/.gitkeep
```

[VS Code screenshot showing faded out files (ignored) and other files which have brighter text (are not ignored)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYUyb.png)

I tried looking at the documentation, but I couldn't find an explanation for this, or at least one I could understand.